# Is there a way to hide HTML content through ampscript if an externally hosted image fails to load?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to know if there's a way to hide HTML content in an email build if an externally hosted image fails to load (images are hosted on AWS). I know I can use ampscript to hide images and content areas in My Portfolio, but am not sure how to approach this with images hosted outside of ExactTarget.

Answer (score 0):

At least there is no reasonable way as AMPscript is rendered at send time. So when checking if the image is available and displaying content based on that response, this represents email send time. So the following would happen:

- **Image is unavailable at send time and available afterwards:** Could be displayed in email now, but isn't as it was unavailable when checking on email send
- **Image is available at send time, but unavailable afterwards:** Now your AMPscript would decide to show the image, but it won't load when as the external image is unavailable at the time the email is openend